# Axios/Vue: How can I tell if Axios is working at all?

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

I have this piece of code in a function called `enviar()` which will send data to the backend server.

```
methods: {
  ...
  enviar() {
    this.editable = false

    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('nombre', this.nombre)

    axios.post('http://test.test/test.php', {
      data: this.data,
      _method: 'patch'
    })
  },
  ...
```

I think it is correct, at least it is according to documentation and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170564/axios-patch-axios-put-is-not-working-in-vue-and-laravel) I read before starting my own.

I have tested so many things, I set up a minimal server (test.test) which has a test.php file which simply is:

```
POST
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>

GET
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
```

I wanted to see if it returns something... and it does!

```
GET
Array
(
)

POST
Array
(
)
```

So both $_POST and `$_GET` are empty arrays. Even if I change the route to `http://test.test/test.php?x=whatever` the `$_GET` is still empty

Am I completely doing everything wrong? Am I not getting the point of Axios and whatever?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457181/axios-posting-params-not-read-by-post can this solve your problem?

Comment: It doesn't but there was a link to another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542123/laravel-vue-js-api-axios-put-method-doesnt-send-any-data-to-controller Unbelievable easy. Anyway, thanks a lot for the heads up!